# Python: Increase List Value (Example[8] = +1 = Example[9]) is this possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

As Described above, i search a method in Python, to increase the Value not from Integers in the List, but from "Example[0]", i want to increase this Value in a loop, basically i open a txt file, let python read it, make it into a List. In the loop i want to: for example jump from 'example[1]' to 'example[8]' is there any way to do that?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: not clear. can you give some black box testing steps?

Comment: from what I can gather you are using for loops and need something to skip elements. My advise is to use while loops in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply define a variable "integer" to index the list and increase that variable itself inside your loop like this:

```py
Example = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
index = 0
print(Example[index])  #  "a"
index += 2
print(Example[index])  #  "c"
```

And if you have a certain step for that index you want to increase it with every time, you can use the [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges) built-in function like this:

```py
Example = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
for index in range(0, len(Example), 2):  # start, stop, step
    print(Example[index])  # "a" "c" "e"
```

Comment: i think you need to reread the question :) (it(the question) is not very clear but i dont think this addresses the question) ... oops maybe i need to reread the question ... honestly no idea now what the question actually is... but this seems like a plausible answer